# Aligning axes in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I was able to render the line graph below with my drawLine function. As you can see, the x-axis tick marks don't align perfectly with the points. How can I shift the x-axis tick marks to the left so that the "10 Sep" tick is right below the y-axis?

[image: Line Graph]

Here's my code:

```
function drawLine(line_data) {
var vizLine = line_data;

var  date_format = d3.time.format("%d %b");
var xline = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var yline = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxisline = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xline)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(date_format);

var yAxisline = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yline)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { 
        return xline(d.date2);
    })
    .y(function(d) { 
        return yline(d.books); 
    });

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

var lineGraph = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

vizLine.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = d[0];
    d.books = +(d[1]);
    d.date2 = Date.parse(d.date);
});

xline.domain(d3.extent(vizLine, function(d) { 
    return d.date2; 
}));
yline.domain([0, d3.max(vizLine, function(d) {
    return (d.books + 1);
})]);

lineGraph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxisline);

lineGraph.append("path")
    .datum(vizLine)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

lineGraph.selectAll("dot")  
    .data(vizLine)          
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5)       
    .attr("cx", function(d) { 
        return xline(d.date2);            
    })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { 
        return yline(d.books);           
    })      
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
        .duration(200)      
        .style("opacity", .9);      
        div.html(d.date + "<br/>"  + d.books + " books")
        .style("width", 70)
        .style("height", 35)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
    })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
        .duration(500)      
        .style("opacity", 0);   
    });     
}
```

Comment: can u provide a working fiddle.

Comment: please provide the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably applying a non-zero x component to the translation of the x axis corrects your bug, but it's hard to tell without seeing the whole code.

Something like

```
lineGraph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxisline);
```